# bookmarks prompting for a name everytime in the same buffer

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

Is it possible to have the default bookmark name ( when we add a bookmark ) as the 
"name of the file: line number" instead of prompting us everytime ? 
Trying to get the bookmark+.el package be similar to bm.el.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the `bookmark-make-record-function` variable to a new routine which creates a default name that you want:

```
(setq bookmark-make-record-function 'my-bookmark-make-record-default)
(defun my-bookmark-make-record-default ()
  "add on a default name for the bookmark"
  (cons (format "%s:%d" (bookmark-buffer-name) (line-number-at-pos (point)))
        (bookmark-make-record-default)))
```

Note: this makes the default name be what you requested (file:line), but you're still prompted - just press <kbd>RET</kbd> to accept the new name.

Answer (score 2):

***[Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus)*** gives you lots of possibilities, including the ability to bookmark files without visiting them and to have the bookmark name be taken automatically from the file name. So I think the OP is mistaken.

See, for instance:

- [Autonamed bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks) -- similar to `bm.el` bookmarks, which you mentioned -- the bookmark name reflects the file name and position in the file.
- [Autofile bookmarks](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks) -- let you treat files like bookmarks (add tags to files etc.) -- the bookmark name is the file name.